# Using jQuery AJAX getting syntax error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and am trying to copy an example from a website I found that uses AJAX I need to take the PHP variable and pass it to another PHP page without refreshing the entire page. I have come up with the following code below but I am getting a syntax error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Here is my code:

```
$("Button").click(function(){
    var textBox = $("textBox").val();
$.post("script.php",
    {textBox: textBox},
     function(data,status)
    )};
)};
```

My PHP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></$
    <title>LCD Display</title>
  </head>
  <body>

        <form id="lcd" action="script.php" method="post">
     <input name='textBox' type='text' />
     <input type='submit' id= 'Button' value='Press to see something cool'/>
     </form>
    <div id='ResponseDiv'>
    </div>

    <iframe id="video" src="http://192.168.0.11:8081" height="120" width="160"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am also getting the following errors but I think they may be related to the syntax error:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type multipart/x-mixed-replace: "http://192.168.0.11:8081/".
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "http://192.168.0.11:8081/".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closing tags:

```
 )};
```

should be this way:

```
$("Button").click(function(){
var textBox = $("textBox").val();
$.post("script.php",
    {textBox: textBox},
      function(data,status){
   });
});
```

and script order will be this way and mind the closing `</$`:

```
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<title>LCD Display</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.post("script.php",
     {textBox: textBox},
     function(data,status){}
   );
```

Also read : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/